# Jeditable displaying whole page in place of edited row

Tags: jquery, struts2, jeditable

I am using Jeditable to edit table rows. My problem is that after submitting the changed value (and storing it in the database) when I return to the page it displays the whole page in place of edited row. It is also displaying outside the table.

```
-------table--------------
row11    row12
row21    row22
--------------------------
```

Suppose I changed `row11` and updated the value in the database. Now the whole table is displayed two times. First under `row11` and the second time outside the table. I cannot figure out why that is happening.

Below is the script I am using for sending the value, and other things:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.edit').editable('', {
            indicator : 'Saving...',
            tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
        });
        $('.edit_area').editable('http://localhost:8080/Interceptors_Struts2_Ant/parameters.action', { 
        type      : 'textarea',
        cancel    : 'Cancel',

        submit    : 'OK',
        indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
        submitdata : function() {
            var id2 = '${param.city}';
            return {city: id2, tableid: $(this).closest('table').attr('id'),
            rowid: $(this).parent().index()}},
            tooltip   : 'Click to edit....',
            name : 'newvalue'
        });
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: nobody is responding...everybody is busy???

Comment: What does this have to do with struts2? In the sense that you would need to know anything about it to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your submitdata return value is now being displayed where the edited element is.
To avoid this, but still keep functionally what I did was to use callback.

```
callback: function(value, settings) {
      $(this).text(value);
   }
```

Add that to your .editable
and have POST action return the text that you want displayed. (value is the return value of post)

Comment: Did you make sure that your post action is returning only the row11 value instead of the whole table?

Comment: i guess thats where i am doing wrong....well as of now i am reloading the whole page in callback function and fetching the entire values from database....so it solved my problem....but yes  you are right....i should make sure it only return the new value...thanks for pointing it out...